# Share Unpublished nodes through a link that needs a user authentication

Tags: users

I am trying to share unpublished node through its URL to a specific role.

What I am trying is that when that user (with the specific role) opens that link, he'd have to login to open the URL.

Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like:

http://example.com/user/login?destination=node/123

That would take them to the login screen and after logging in they would be taken to node 123

Answer (score 4):

[Access unpublished](https://www.drupal.org/project/access_unpublished)

> Easy to use module grants access to view unpublished content to anyone
>   who has a unique URL and appropriate permissions. Visitor can be
>   anonymous or authenticated user with the user role.
>
> When administrator or users with enabled privileges visit (or save)
>   unpublished node, can see link for direct view that unpublished
>   content. Unique URL link is displayed as Drupal message or in node
>   content.
>
> Administrator can enable view an unpublished node for any roles with
>   "View unpublished contents" permission. If it is set for anonymous
>   users, anyone who know the link with hash key, can view the
>   unpublished node. View only, not edit.
>
> Default URL parameter is "hash" and can be changed on configuration
>   page for more security or customization.
>
> Module is useful for proofreaders, content checkers etc. Webmaster
>   does not need to create user accounts and can keep the website safer.
>   Each node has its own unique hash key (like Google Docs).

Answer (score 3):

You may want to use the [view_unpublished](https://www.drupal.org/project/view_unpublished) module. Some more details about it, from its project page:

> This module allows you to grant access for **specific** user roles to view unpublished nodes of a **specific** type. Access control is quite granular in this regard.